# Node.js : How to add print job to printer

Tags: node.js, pdf, printers

I am developing a web application using node.js where i have a scenario to print some pdf files located in my local.

Ex:

```
var ipp = require('ipp');
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

//make a PDF document
var doc = new PDFDocument({margin:0});
doc.text(".", 0, 780);

doc.output(function(pdf){
    var printer = ipp.Printer("http://NPI977E4E.local.:631/ipp/printer");
    var msg = {
        "operation-attributes-tag": {
            "requesting-user-name": "William",
            "job-name": "My Test Job",
            "document-format": "application/pdf"
        },
        data: pdf
    };
    printer.execute("Print-Job", msg, function(err, res){
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

I have referred the above example, but in that PDF is created but in my case i want to print the existing PDF files.

Any suggestions ???

Answer (score 4):

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('filename.pdf', function(err, data) { 
  if (err)
    throw err;

  var printer = ipp.Printer("http://YOUR.PRINTER.SERVER.HOSTNAME:631/ipp/printer");
  var msg = {
    "operation-attributes-tag": {
      "requesting-user-name": "William",
      "job-name": "My Test Job",
      "document-format": "application/pdf"
    },
    data: data
  };
  printer.execute("Print-Job", msg, function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

Comment: And what does `err` say? BTW, just cutting and pasting the example code obviously isn't going to work, unless your printer is located on a server called `NPI977E4E.local` as well.

Comment: { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }

Comment: So replace `NPI977E4E.local` with the address or hostname of your IPP server.

Comment: i changed host name of printer and checked then its showing 'null'.

Comment: When `err` is null, that means no error occurred. Which should be a good thing.

Comment: when i print res it shows. { version: '1.1',
  statusCode: 'server-error-version-not-supported',
  id: 36143315,
  'operation-attributes-tag':
   { 'attributes-charset': 'utf-8',
     'attributes-natural-language': 'en-us' } }

Comment: Well, I guess your problem is a bit more elaborate that just wanting to print local files instead of generated ones. It might even warrant a new (or reformulated) question to attract people with more knowledge.

Comment: This is late, but chances are that all you needed to do was specify the version that is provided in the request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print local PDF files, and printing works already?

Node.js has the fs api you can use to retrieve a PDF file.
http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

https://npmjs.org/package/ipp To me it doesn't seem you have to use a PDFkit object as data -property in your operation. You can just use data you can read with fs.

Comment: Try to get your address and network configuration working first, and try to just print that in-line created PDF in your example.
Make small steps.