# Get the output from printer using print in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some values in my screen , i need to print(through printer) only values in the screen by using JavaScript or j query , Is there is any inbuilt function ? except print();

Thanks as advance.

Comment: Unclear what you want to a happen....

Comment: I don't think there's any way for Javascript to send to the printer directly. The only method is `window.print()`.

Comment: also, the javascript print() function actually has nothing to do with printing to paper - it simply writes additional text to the HTML of the currently loaded page.

Comment: This is as close as you are going to get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456717/how-can-i-print-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to print some data directly, but you can use a work around method to do it
**Try this function**

```
function print_specific_content() {
    var content = "Printed using Ahmed El-Essawy Code";

    var win = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=800,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
    win.document.write("<html><body onload=\"window.print(); window.close();\">" + content + "</body></html>");
    win.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU you want to SEND values to printer. If it's not the case please report back.

Javascript is traditionally a client-side language, so you don't have direct access to hardware. However with the advent of server javascript libraries (like Node.js) you do have server modules (as node-printer) that allow you to print things (like the examples in this answer: [Node.js : How to add print job to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187936/node-js-how-to-add-print-job-to-printer))

So you would have to have a Node.js module that do the printing you want, and you would have to call it with and ajax function or something to print the values.

Hope I clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You can print your specific text from the web page by using **CSS** `@media print`

**Here is an example :**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="doNotPrint"></div>
  <div class="printThisSection">
    <!-- HERE IS THE HTML CODES FOR PRINT-->
  </div>
  <div class="doNotPrint"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS :**

```
@media print{
  .doNotPrint{ /*This section will never print*/
    display: none;
  }
  /*Your other CSS property here*/
}
```

> **Note :** You can use shortcut `ctrl` `+` `p` to show print popup instead of using `window.print()`